# Azure - how can I find Azure service name by hostname/machine name?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-appservice, azure-app-service-envrmnt

I have hostname/machine name from logs. I want to know what service is running that. is there any way I can backtrack service name by hostname/machine name?

I tried to search for all queries, tried kudu but can see hostname for the service I select. cant reverse search it

Comment: Could you please confirm if your query is for azure-webapp-service or if you are using Virtual machine, check this link on viewing and modifying hostname, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-networks-viewing-and-modifying-hostnames

Comment: Yes Azure App Service, I have hostname/machine name with me and trying to search App service name it is linked to.

Comment: Are you trying to get all the services by using hostname ?- @ppp940

Answer (score 0):

After I've done workaround, there is no direct command to get azure app service with hostname, but I found an alternative to get App Service details with hostnames by using:

***`Get-Azurermwebapp`*** *command with the respective resource group name.*

With  ***`Get-Azurermwebapp`*** command, Direct hostname retrieval is not supported via a parameter. To do that, I gave the information to a variable and used it to retrieve.

```
 get-azurermwebapp -ResourceGroupName <ResourceGroupName>
 $info =  get-azurermwebapp -ResourceGroupName <ResourceGroupName> #Storing in info variable
 $info.name #retrieving Azure App service names
 $hostname = $info.enabledhostnames #retrieve enabledhostnames by passing info to $hostname
 $hostname
```

[image]

[image]

*Note*: If you need to view all services operating inside any AzureVM, together with their status, Use `Get-service`:

`get-service -computername <VMName>`

[image]

[image]

Refer [MsDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Azurerm.Websites/Get-AzureRmWebApp?redirectedfrom=msdn&view=azurermps-6.13.0)